# How to move an object faster through an arc - Unity

Tags: unity, physics, rigidbody

I'm shooting a ball in an arc, but currently it takes too long to move through the arc, so when I increase the force, it doesn't make the ball move faster through the arc, it just launches the ball farther.

Here is my code:

```
private void Start() {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    Vector3 direction = new Vector3(0, 1, 1);

    rb.AddForce(direction * 8, ForceMode.Impulse);
}
```

How can I make the ball move through the arc faster, but not increase the range?

Comment: Under a fixed gravity, travel along a particular arc takes a fixed amount of time. If you want to arrive faster, you and either travel the same arc with higher gravity, or flatten your arc to take a more direct path under the same gravity. Which do you want to change: your (local) gravity, or your arc?

Comment: This is what I was speculating I would have to do. Is it possible to adjust only the gravity of an object and not all objects?

Comment: Yes. In 2D you can adjust the gravity scale. In 3D you can apply a downward acceleration to it each FixedUpdate via a C# script. Would you like an answer that demonstrates that?